# Nuxt Authentication API calls strategies

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, nuxtjs

I have some unfamiliar API calls in the current app I'm building. It needs a couple of parameters to setup the following api's. Currently based on subdomain in window it picks up the url parameter to create the first API call. After that I use Vuex store to store the relevant information for the organization data.

I'm currently trying to setup authorization and unfortunately due to it being inside `nuxt.config.js` I can't dynamically add data from the vuex store. Here is an example of the strategies I've set up. I'm currently using the local default strategies, but wan't to make the url requests dynamic:

`nuxt.config.js`

```
 /*
   ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios', '@nuxtjs/auth'],
  /*
   ** Axios configuration
   */
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'https://api.getconflux.com',
    headers: {
      common: {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
      }
    }
  },
  /*
   ** Auth configuration
   */
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'token'
          },
          logout: {
            url: '/logout',
            method: 'post'
          },
          user: {
            url: '/supporters/me',
            headers: {
              'organization-id': getters.companyId,
              // Authorization Bearer needs to be automatically called from login
            },
            method: 'get',
            propertyName: 'voter'
          },
        }
      }
    },
    customStrategy: {
      user: '~/schemas/user'
    },
    redirect: {
      home: '/'
    }
  }
```

The current login I manually setup, with no url as I call that when my index page loads. This is the first api call to build out my state with the required data I need to call for my subsequent api calls after that.

For my auth api request to work, especially the `fetchUser()` call in the `user` strategy I need to get the companyId getter/state from my store. I have no idea how to do this here?

Does anyone have an idea of how I can best implement that?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You could disable the user endpoint in the `nuxt.config.js` file and then manually call the endpoint in Vuex to fetch the user details then pass it on to the `setUser` method of the auth NuxtJS module. So in your `nuxt.config.js` file, you should have this:

```js
/*
   ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios', '@nuxtjs/auth'],
  /*
   ** Axios configuration
   */
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'https://api.getconflux.com',
    headers: {
      common: {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
      }
    }
  },
  /*
   ** Auth configuration
   */
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'token'
          },
          logout: {
            url: '/logout',
            method: 'post'
          },
          user: false
    },
    customStrategy: {
      user: '~/schemas/user'
    },
    redirect: {
      home: '/'
    }
  }
```

Then in your store, you have an action(or a mutation making the API request to get the user details). Then you call `setUser` as described [here](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth.html#setuser-user)

Comment: Thanks Kelvin! The only thing I'm struggling with at this point is figuring out where to call it. I set up an action which is `fetchUser` but I need that to run globally every time a user accesses the app. I want to do a check to see if `loggedIn` then call the custom `fetchUser` action in my store. Do you know how I may go about doing that? When I set `user` in strategies to false, it doesn't automatically make an api request, which is kind of what I need, just with additional parameters. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: You can trigger the fetchUser action after the user logs in(which is also what the user endpoint is doing under the hood). So when a new user successfully logs in, you make an API request using the fetchUser action and populate the auth module with setUser

Comment: Ah okay thanks! But will that happen even after a full reload of the page? Because currently that’s not happening. If you reload the page the user data gets lost but the loggedIn state is true.  Or would I need to make a separate fetch of the user data if they’ve already logged in based on the loggedIn boolean? Also my login endpoint contains the user data initially by the way, token along with the user data.

Comment: That’s good. I think setUser stores the value using local storage so you should have persistence.